# Android - How to Align Views Inside the Table Rows Created Programmatically

Tags: java, android

I'm creating some table layout rows and then some views inside this. I'd like to align these views.

There is only one TableLayout in my layout and java code in is below.

**My Java Code:**

```
TableLayout ll = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.displayLinear);

        for (int i = 0; i <2; i++) {

            TableRow row= new TableRow(this);
            TableRow.LayoutParams lp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            row.setLayoutParams(lp);

            TextView tv1 = new TextView(this);
            TextView tv2 = new TextView(this);

            tv1.setText("---Align Left This---");
            tv2.setText("---Align Right This---");


            row.addView(tv1);
            row.addView(tv2);
            ll.addView(row,i);
        }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this

```
myTable.setColumnStretchable(2, true);
```

or

```
textView.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT)
```

tell me if it works

see more in: [Aligning TextViews in a TableRow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6367494/aligning-textviews-in-a-tablerow)

or here

[Programmatically set TextView gravity right in a TableRow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27909357/programmatically-set-textview-gravity-right-in-a-tablerow)

good luck

Comment: Hey          tv2.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
            ll.setColumnStretchable(1, true);
worked!!